# IntelliJ: Cannot copy resources and compile

Tags: java, csv, intellij-idea

I have been trying since 45 minutes to run my program in IntelliJ where the code takes in 45mb CSV file and performs Scientific calculations and produces around 430000 output files in CSV format with Simulated results.

Since past 1 hour I have tried repeatedly to restart IntelliJ and reload the files but to my misery, since an hour the IDE is absolutely blocked, it cannot copy the resources from input file or do any process

Let me know some ways in which I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Sorry its a commercial project, comprising of over million lines of Code. how can i send it, its unfortunately not possible, i am just running few modules in parallel and since 1 hour i started facing the problems

Comment: Don't show the whole thing. Only part where you work with CSV. It's the part, where the error happens, right? If you not going to help us help you, then you're on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ has a readNext() method that is a bit more memory efficient than loading the entire file at once. That may stop you from having to load all 45 MBs of CSV all at once.

Comment: Thanks very much, actually my entire module is over 1 GB with some additional useless Junk files , thats why it took lot of time to load ,,I resolved it